# trigger event on cross-origin window

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a website. In this website i display diffrent movies and series. Now when you select a episode of a serie this episode gets opened on bs.to in chrome if you look at the website (https://bs.to/serie/One-Piece/6/4-jfdsf/de) you see the play-button in the middle of the screen. is it possible to trigger a click event on this button for example with postMessage(). I've tried to add an eventlistener to the window and also to fire a event but i allways get the DOMException Blocked a frame from accessing cross-origin frame.

Is there a work-around? or can i develop a programm whitch simulate clicks dosen't metter if a window is opened or not?

Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `bs.to` listens for a message telling it to fire a click…

```
addEventListener('message', e => document.querySelector("button").click())
```

… then yes.

But there is no way for your site to make the user's browser trigger a click on a third party site without that sites explicit cooperation.

That would be a huge security problem (take, for example, a third party site that was your online banking service, and a series of clicks that would transfer all your money to a malicious site author's account).

Comment: that's make sense and can i trigger an Event independently of the opened Programm or window just with x and y?